# mu4e does not list all messages in INBOX

Tags: email, emacs, mu

I have installed and configured `mu` and `mu4e` as explained in the [manual](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/) (newest version on emacs 24.3.1). My `mu4e` config contains:

```lisp
(setq mu4e-maildir "~/Maildir/mail_user_de")

(setq mu4e-drafts-folder "/Drafts")
(setq mu4e-sent-folder   "/Sent")
(setq mu4e-trash-folder  "/Trash")
```

These folders exist and each contains three subfolders: `cur`, `new` and `tmp`. When I fire up `mu4e` it says:

> [mu4e] Started mu4e with 4023 messages in store

however, when I enter the `INBOX` folder, there is no mail listed. On the other hand, when I enter the *last 7 days* bookmark, all emails from the last seven days are listed.

My assumption is, that `mu4e` does not care for emails which have been downloaded **outside** of emacs because

1. When I update (calling `offlineimap` and `mu index`) within `mu4e` the email are sorted correctly into the `INBOX`
2. When I update **outside** of emacs, the mails are listed in the bookmark but **not** in the `INBOX` until they are marked read **outside of `mu4e`**. If this happens outside of `mu4e` they will not show up in the `INBOX`, otherwise they will suddenly appear (flagged read) in the `INBOX`.

Obviously I don't like this. I would prefer if all mails, independent whether they were downloaded from within `mu4e` or directly in a terminal, show up in the `INBOX`. Is this a bug or a feature (which, so I hope, can be disabled)?

Comment: How did you solve this? The answer below does not work for me.

Comment: The same happened to me and it was because the index had not been done properly for some reason: the parent directory was missing from the maildir, i.e. messages were indexed as in the folder `/INBOX` whereas they were in the folder `/whatever/INBOX`. Rebuilding the index with `mu index --rebuild` solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into something similar.  I suspect it's because I had mu index ~/Maildir rather than ~/Maildir/mail_user_de (using your setup as an example), but I haven't checked.  Regardless, the following change worked for me:

```
(setq mu4e-maildir "~/Maildir")
(setq mu4e-drafts-folder "/mail_user_de/Drafts")
(setq mu4e-sent-folder   "/mail_user_de/Sent")
(setq mu4e-trash-folder  "/mail_user_de/Trash")
```

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Comment: That solution worked for me but made things complicated in other ways. I ended up rebuilding the mu index specifying the maildir location like: ~/Maildir//mail_user_de. Solved it straight away.